# gnome-shell crashes when mounting, umounting usb drives

Tags: debian, gnome3, gnome-shell

When I plug/unplug (mount/umount) any usb flash drive, every GUI application is killed and I get back to gnome login page. On the other hand the non-gui applications keep working (e.g those that had been executed through ctrl-alt-f2)

I ran rkhunter, and it didn't report anything suspicious.

I am running (debian sid):

```
Linux mypc 4.14.0-3-rt-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Debian 4.14.13-1 (2018-01-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux

GNOME Shell 3.26.2
```

The log files that seem to be affected are:

*** dmesg:**

```
< [ 1022.224350] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 80
< [ 1022.224612] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 80
< [ 1081.212308] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
< [ 1081.368128] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
< [ 1081.368133] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
< [ 1081.368203] usb 2-1: Product: Intenso Rainbow Line
< [ 1081.368206] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Alcor
< [ 1081.368210] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 12345678
< [ 1081.369361] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
< [ 1081.369584] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
< [ 1082.390361] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Intenso  Rainbow Line     8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
< [ 1082.391791] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
< [ 1082.392270] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 62410752 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
< [ 1082.392944] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
< [ 1082.392946] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
< [ 1082.393623] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
< [ 1082.397401]  sdc: sdc1
< [ 1082.400993] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
< [ 1082.827871] EXT4-fs (sdc1): recovery complete
< [ 1082.835572] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
< [ 1083.084008] rfkill: input handler enabled
< [ 1089.711837] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
< [ 1089.761233] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
< [ 1089.761241] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 3702784, lost sync page write
< [ 1089.761249] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc1-8.
< [ 1089.761253] Aborting journal on device sdc1-8.
< [ 1089.761259] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
< [ 1089.761261] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 3702784, lost sync page write
< [ 1089.761265] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc1-8.
< [ 1089.761469] EXT4-fs (sdc1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
< [ 1089.761476] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
< [ 1097.258447] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

*** /var/log/syslog:**

```
    < Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Some code accessed the property 'EmailAccount' on the module 'EmailAccount'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: [Email Message Tray] Init version 9
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: [Email Message Tray] Enabling 9
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: error: No email accounts found
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gsd-rfkill[7071]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-noinput'
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc kernel: [ 1097.258447] rfkill: input handler disabled
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: [Email Message Tray] No email accounts found,Extension<._getGoaAccounts@/home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/GmailMessageTray@shuming0207.gmail.com/extension.js:97:19#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012Extension<._init@/home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/GmailMessageTray@shuming0207.gmail.com/extension.js:65:28#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_Base.prototype._construct@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:18:5#012Class.prototype._construct/newClass@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:114:32#012enable@/home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/GmailMessageTray@shuming0207.gmail.com/extension.js:128:21#012enableExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:129:9#012loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:171:17#012_loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:318:9#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:126:27#012ExtensionFinder<._loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:184:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012bind/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/lang.js:97:16#012collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:17#012ExtensionFinder<.scanExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:189:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:320:5#012enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:328:9#012_sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:359:9#012init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:367:5#012_initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:217:5#012start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:126:5#012@<main>:1:31
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gsd-sharing[7083]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: System monitor applet init from /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: System monitor applet enabling
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: JS WARNING: [/home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/extension.js 1507]: reference to undefined property "Client"
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension "system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com" had error: TypeError: NMClient.Client is undefined
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Some code accessed the property 'PlacesManager' on the module 'placeDisplay'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Extension workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/stelarov/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7' unit='evolution-calendar-factory.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=7000 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server ")
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc systemd[6869]: Starting Evolution calendar service...
< Jan 26 15:54:59 mypc bluetoothd[680]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore was not provided by any .service files
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7'
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc systemd[6869]: Started Evolution calendar service.
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.51' (uid=1000 pid=7178 comm="gdbus call -e -d org.freedesktop.DBus -o /org/free")
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc systemd[6869]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc dbus-daemon[673]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service' requested by ':1.153' (uid=1000 pid=7105 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard ")
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc systemd[6869]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc tracker-store.desktop[7178]: (uint32 1,)
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc gnome-session-binary[6891]: Entering running state
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc gsd-power[7067]: gsd_power_backlight_abs_to_percentage: assertion 'max > min' failed
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc dbus-daemon[673]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
< Jan 26 15:55:00 mypc systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9' unit='evolution-addressbook-factory.service' requested by ':1.61' (uid=1000 pid=7146 comm="/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subp")
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc systemd[6869]: Starting Evolution address book service...
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9'
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc systemd[6869]: Started Evolution address book service.
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: GNOME Shell started at Fri Jan 26 2018 15:54:59 GMT+0200 (EET)
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc CRON[7291]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.56' (uid=1000 pid=7188 comm="/usr/lib/tracker/tracker-extract ")
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc systemd[6869]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc dbus-daemon[6889]: [session uid=1000 pid=6889] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc systemd[6869]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract.desktop[7188]: Duplicate property or field node
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract.desktop[7188]: Duplicate property or field node
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract.desktop[7188]: Duplicate property or field node
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract.desktop[7188]: Duplicate property or field node
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract.desktop[7188]: Duplicate property or field node
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: Could not insert metadata for item "file:///home/stelarov/Documents/mine/afm.jpg": Unable to insert multiple values for subject `urn:uuid:1a502c34-2d90-58a6-205b-cbd30009334d' and single valued property `nie:contentCreated' (old_value: '<untransformable>', new value: '<untransformable>')
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: If the error above is recurrent for the same item/ID, consider running "tracker-extract" in the terminal with the TRACKER_VERBOSITY=3 environment variable, and filing a bug with the additional information
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: Could not insert metadata for item "file:///home/stelarov/Documents/mine/sbarberakis_driv_licence1.jpg": Unable to insert multiple values for subject `urn:uuid:457d564e-b265-2729-e171-7c4a41bbcf97' and single valued property `nmm:exposureTime' (old_value: '0.030303', new value: '0.071429')
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: If the error above is recurrent for the same item/ID, consider running "tracker-extract" in the terminal with the TRACKER_VERBOSITY=3 environment variable, and filing a bug with the additional information
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: Could not insert metadata for item "file:///home/stelarov/Documents/mine/sbarberakis_driv_licence1.jpg": Unable to insert multiple values for subject `urn:uuid:457d564e-b265-2729-e171-7c4a41bbcf97' and single valued property `nmm:exposureTime' (old_value: '0.030303', new value: '0.071429')
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: If the error above is recurrent for the same item/ID, consider running "tracker-extract" in the terminal with the TRACKER_VERBOSITY=3 environment variable, and filing a bug with the additional information
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: Could not insert metadata for item "file:///home/stelarov/Documents/mine/sbarberakis_licence_2.jpg": Unable to insert multiple values for subject `urn:uuid:8f82b450-5524-b79f-98af-04032937a833' and single valued property `nie:contentCreated' (old_value: '<untransformable>', new value: '<untransformable>')
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: If the error above is recurrent for the same item/ID, consider running "tracker-extract" in the terminal with the TRACKER_VERBOSITY=3 environment variable, and filing a bug with the additional information
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: Could not insert metadata for item "file:///home/stelarov/Documents/mine/sbarberakis_licence_2.jpg": Unable to insert multiple values for subject `urn:uuid:8f82b450-5524-b79f-98af-04032937a833' and single valued property `nie:contentCreated' (old_value: '<untransformable>', new value: '<untransformable>')
< Jan 26 15:55:01 mypc tracker-extract[7188]: If the error above is recurrent for the same item/ID, consider running "tracker-extract" in the terminal with the TRACKER_VERBOSITY=3 environment variable, and filing a bug with the additional information
< Jan 26 15:55:02 mypc gnome-software[7179]: plugin appstream took 1.8 seconds to do setup
< Jan 26 15:55:02 mypc gnome-software[7179]: enabled plugins: packagekit-refresh, packagekit-proxy, shell-extensions, os-release, packagekit-offline, fwupd, packagekit-local, desktop-categories, systemd-updates, packagekit, packagekit-upgrade, appstream, hardcoded-featured, odrs, desktop-menu-path, hardcoded-popular, generic-updates, packagekit-refine, modalias, rewrite-resource, hardcoded-blacklist, steam, packagekit-history, provenance, icons, provenance-license, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
< Jan 26 15:55:02 mypc gnome-software[7179]: disabled plugins: dummy, dpkg, repos, epiphany
< Jan 26 15:55:02 mypc gnome-software[7179]: failed to call gs_plugin_add_updates_historical on fwupd: The name org.freedesktop.fwupd was not provided by any .service files
< Jan 26 15:55:07 mypc terminator[7329]: Allocating size to GtkVScrollbar 0x5652b4cb2330 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
< Jan 26 15:55:08 mypc terminator[7329]: Allocating size to GtkVScrollbar 0x5652b4cb2330 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
< Jan 26 15:55:08 mypc terminator[7329]: Allocating size to GtkVScrollbar 0x5652b4cb2330 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
< Jan 26 15:55:08 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer event5 debounce: offset negative (-2426)
< Jan 26 15:55:08 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer event5 debounce short: offset negative (-15454)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Object St.Widget (0x55e1e53ebc10), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e1e36ee000 ==
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #0 0x55e1e3a739f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:73 (0x7fdeac5ddef0 @ 9)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #1 0x55e1e3a73978 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:105 (0x7fdeac5df230 @ 36)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #2 0x55e1e3a738f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:92 (0x7fdeac5df098 @ 52)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #3 0x7ffd299ba3f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:203 (0x7fdeac5e9cd0 @ 54)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #4 0x7ffd299ba540 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:332 (0x7fdeac5e9d58 @ 1626)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #5 0x7ffd299ba5f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:345 (0x7fdeac5e9de0 @ 100)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #6 0x7ffd299ba680 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:360 (0x7fdeac5e9e68 @ 10)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #7 0x7ffd299ba770 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:126 (0x7fdeac5e2b38 @ 386)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #8 0x7ffd299ba820 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:208 (0x7fdeac5df808 @ 159)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #9 0x7ffd299ba880 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fdeac5c2bc0 @ 71)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #10 0x7ffd299ba930 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:183 (0x7fdeac5df780 @ 20)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #11 0x7ffd299baa00 b   self-hosted:917 (0x7fdeac5ee5e8 @ 394)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e1e36ee000 ==
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #0 0x55e1e3a739f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:80 (0x7fdeac5ddef0 @ 82)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #1 0x55e1e3a73978 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:105 (0x7fdeac5df230 @ 36)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #2 0x55e1e3a738f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:92 (0x7fdeac5df098 @ 52)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #3 0x7ffd299ba3f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:203 (0x7fdeac5e9cd0 @ 54)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #4 0x7ffd299ba540 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:332 (0x7fdeac5e9d58 @ 1626)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #5 0x7ffd299ba5f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:345 (0x7fdeac5e9de0 @ 100)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #6 0x7ffd299ba680 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:360 (0x7fdeac5e9e68 @ 10)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #7 0x7ffd299ba770 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:126 (0x7fdeac5e2b38 @ 386)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc gnome-shell[6947]: Object St.Widget (0x55e1e53ebc10), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #8 0x7ffd299ba820 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:208 (0x7fdeac5df808 @ 159)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #9 0x7ffd299ba880 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fdeac5c2bc0 @ 71)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #10 0x7ffd299ba930 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:183 (0x7fdeac5df780 @ 20)
< Jan 26 15:55:10 mypc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6947]: #11 0x7ffd299baa00 b   self-hosted:917 (0x7fdeac5ee5e8 @ 394)
```

`.xsession-errors` and `./local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` didn't change during the crash

Any ideas where I should be looking for any clues? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to get access to the USB drive?

Comment: Yep after logging in again, everything (including the usb) works fine, until I umount the usb

Comment: I experienced the same issue (debian sid) when unmounted a plain USB flash drive. The same happens when I connect my android phone. Could not find anything in the logs though. The USB drive worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be the places-status-indicator extension.

My gnome-shell 3.26.2 session crashes (under Wayland) when mounting/unmounting an external USB disk or when unmounting a disk from an external USB DVD drive.

Bugs I found:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/issues/48
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/issues/44
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/issues/33

Running gjs 1.50.3 here. No newer release tag found.

Looking at the activity in the issue trackers, this seems to be a quite recent thingy cropping up.

**UPDATE: 2018-02-07:**

An update to `gjs` has been [released as 1.50.4](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/ftp-release-list/2018-January/msg00073.html). An updated Fedora package arrived [yesterday](https://www.spinics.net/lists/fedora-package-announce/msg235341.html).
Plugging and unplugging an USB device works again with activate `places-status-indicator` extension.

Comment: Yep, uninstalling `places-status-indicator` solved the problem! Thank you very much

Comment: It crashes under xorg too, disabling the extension fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related but I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 20.10 where gnome-shell would crash during usage of usb drives or connecting my phone. After going into Extensions and turning off Desktop Icons I haven't had any more issues.